# Question marks (?) in due to ru_RU.UTF-8 lc_messages, postgresql, redos7.3.2

Tags: linux, postgresql, locale, redhat, psql

I have a problem... When I set ru_RU.UTF-8 locale into lc group parameters in postgresql.conf my messges after starting the cluster with pg_ctl turn into question marks (?). Meanwhile some of my rus text is ok in console, some are not. How can I solve this problem?

A few moments, I'm using redos docker container without systemd, with LC_ALL = ru_RU.UTF-8 when I execute initdb. On Ubuntu, for example, there are no problems with that, unlike redos.

My text should be completely in Russian.

Comment: What is normal? Do you want to see error and log messages in English or in Russian?

Comment: in Russian, no messages on English

Comment: How is this a problem related to any Dockerfile (which you haven't shared)  or psql? Is this even related to programming?

Comment: Where did you see those question marks? Post an actual example. Question marks appear when you try to read text or display text data with the wrong single-byte codepage. If a *Unicode* encoding was used to read, you'd see �. If an application or terminal tried to read or show UTF8 text as eg Latin1 or Cyrillic, you'd see  mangled text or a `?` for every byte outside the 0x00-0x7F range.

Comment: My docker container should have everything necessary so that when starting the cluster, the problem described above does not occur. My docker file does not matter in this case, the only thing worth adding to the main question is that I have LC_ALL set to the appropriate locale when initializing the cluster and there are no such problems on ubuntu, but there are some on redos.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If this problem is not related to the Dockerfile you've used, please remove the tag

Comment: After your latest edits: please keep in mind that StackOverflow is a site for programming related issues. If this is solely related to configuring any server application, please move your problem to serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

The text is completely in Russian. You have to fix your terminal so that it displays Russian UTF-8 characters correctly.

Comment: This is formally the question, how can I do this?

Comment: That depends on the operating system and the terminal that you are using. You didn't specify the latter.

Comment: Maybe something like that?!(

Answer (score 0):

**Settings of the client terminal window, current database client and server encoding, locale setting of database have to be synchronised.**

1. To check current client terminal windows encoding, which for example in my case is a Translation of Remote caracter set from Window by putty.exe
   Choose from 'Saved Sessions', push 'Load' and Verify Settings
   at the ‘Window’ panel -> 'Translation' -> Remote caracter set:
   UTF-8
   [image]
2. To check current client and server encoding from PSQL:

   postgres=#SELECT name, setting, context, sourcefile FROM pg_settings WHERE name LIKE '%encoding%';
   [image]

The value of the client_encoding parameter is set by the client - psql. When psql starts, it sets client_encoding to match the client OS encoding based on the LC_CTYPE variable in the OS by default. If that failed, then for client_encoding would choosed by  psql second default value - the encoding of the database to which we are connecting.

The value of the parameter server_encoding is set internally by the postgres server backend for the corresponding current connection through psql by value of current database encoding, correlated with its datcollate, datctype.

3. To check locale setting of the claster database from PSQL:
   (* lc_ctype and lc_collate are set when the cluster is initialized and cannot be changed without re-creating the cluster.)

   postgres=#`SELECT name, setting FROM pg_settings  WHERE name LIKE '%lc%';`
   [image]
4. To check locale Collate and Ctype setting of databases from PSQL:
   (** It is impossible to change them without recreating the specific database.
   *** locale character encodings (lc_ctype and lc_collate) must match
   with database encoding.)
   postgres=#select datname, datcollate, DatCtype from pg_database;
   [image]
   or:
   postgres=# \list
   [image]

URL docs of postgrespro.ru:

- [Chapter 24. Localization](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/16/locale?lang=en)
- [24.3. Character Set Support](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/16/multibyte?lang=en)
- [Education Free Course](https://edu.postgrespro.ru/dba2-13/dba2_16_admin_localization.html)

**If you got a discrepancy of current database client and server encoding for example:**

```
SELECT name, setting, context, sourcefile 
FROM pg_settings
WHERE name LIKE '%encoding%';
```

[image]

1. Change setting of client_encoding:

   postgres=#set client_encoding to UTF8;
   [image]

or:
postgres=#\encoding UTF8

[image: UTF8]

To check only current client encoding from PSQL:

```
postgres=#select pg_client_encoding();
```

[image]

or:
postgres=#\encoding
or:
postgres=#SHOW client_encoding;

[image]

To check current client and server encoding:
postgres=#SELECT name, setting, context
FROM pg_settings
WHERE name LIKE '%encoding%';

[image]

2. To change current client terminal windows encoding, which (for example in my case) - putty.exe:

Еxcerption from PuTTY User Manual:
"3.3 Altering your character set configuration
If you click ‘Change Settings’ and look at the ‘Translation’ panel,
you should see a large number of character sets which you can select, and other related options.
Now all you need is to find out which of them you want!"
from the list correct encoding:UTF-8

UTF-8
Win1251 (Cyrillic)
KOI8-R
ISO-8859-5:1999 (Latin/Cyrillic)
[image]

**If your terminal does not support the server encoding, you need to force the server torrent for the client to be encoded into that client terminal encoding by applying psql client encoding.**

For example, a list of conversions for Russian koi8 encoding:

```
\dcS *koi8*
```

[image]

To apply psql client encoding:

```
\encoding KOI8R
```

[image]

But nota bene: [If the client character set is defined as SQL_ASCII, encoding conversion is disabled, regardless of the server's character set.](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/16/multibyte?lang=en)

i.e.: If PostgreSQL databases have been created with SQL_ASCII encoding and LC_CTYPE is not C or POSIX then this prone to locale-dependent misbehavior. When the server character set is SQL_ASCII, the server interprets byte values 0–127 according to the ASCII standard, while byte values 128–255 are taken as uninterpreted characters. No encoding conversion will be done when the setting is SQL_ASCII.

For more info see URL:
[Automatic Character Set Conversion Between Server and Client](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/16/multibyte?lang=en#MULTIBYTE-AUTOMATIC-CONVERSION?lang=en)